# Pegar a pasta da aplicação

Tags: c#, .net, diretório

Eu tenho uma aplicação com todas as interfaces e funcionalidades. No mesmo projeto coloquei um simples código rodando em console para verificar se já existe o banco de dados criado na máquina. Caso não, ele deverá executar o *script* que cria isso. O código é o seguinte:

```
public static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        static extern bool FreeConsole();

        [STAThread]
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
            {

                Console.ReadLine();
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                String connString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
                String cmdText = "select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name= 'db_teste'";
                Boolean bRet;

                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection);
                try
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                    bRet = reader.HasRows;
                    sqlConnection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    bRet = false;
                    sqlConnection.Close();
                    Console.Write(e.Message);
                }

                if (bRet == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Atualizando Tabelas...");

                }
                else
                {
                    string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
                    var file = new FileInfo(@"C://script.sql");
                    string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
                    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
                    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);

                }
                FreeConsole();
                var app = new App();
                return app.Run();
            }

        }
```

Essa sempre é a primeira parte a ser executada pelo programa quando ele roda. Bom, eu crio instaladores com Visual Studio Installer - > setup wizard.

Como acessar o script SQL?

```
var file = new FileInfo(@"C://script.sql");
```

Nesse trecho `FileInfo` buscará como referência o que já está *setado*, mas se durante a instalação o usuário escolher um outro local para instalar o aplicativo a aplicação não conseguirá localizar o arquivo `.sql`. Como posso solucionar isso?

No projeto *setup* adicionei o arquivo na pasta do projeto onde ficam algumas DLL.

[image: SS]

Erro ao executar:
[image: SS]

Comment: Este arquivo sempre estará na pasta onde a aplicação está executando?

Comment: @bigown bom isso que eu quero mas não sei como fazer isso durante o processo de criação do instalador. Talvez com a opção de adicionar pastas ao projeto, mas enfim como eu posso referenciar se for na pasta onde a aplicação está executando?

Comment: Respondi em cima do que me disse, se precisar pegar em um diretório arbitrário, precisa modificar o instalador para informar para a aplicação onde está, aí é outra resposta mas nem tem a ver com a aplicação e seria outra pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código tem alguns problemas mas vou te passar só o que perguntou:

```
var file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"script.sql"));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zoGoe7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sidkOV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetAppFolder.cs).

Comment: quais tipos de problemas teria? Poderia até fazer uma nova pergunta. Mas quais seriam?

Comment: A lista é longa :) A mistura de console com WPF, a forma como trata exceção, abertura e fechamento de arquivos e outros pequenos detalhes menos importantes.

Comment: na verdade não encontrei uma outra solução para conseguir executar um script sql durante a primeira execução do software. Existem outras maneira mais simples ao invés de console com wpf?

Comment: Só o WPF. Isto é invenção, é ir do Rio a SP passando por BH.

Comment: tive um erro fazendo fileinfo. Vou posta a imagem.

Comment: Isto é outro problema e tem a ver com o projeto e não com o código. Você está misturando versões do .Net. Seu projeto deve estar uma confusão enorme.